# Calling Snarl from java code

Tags: java, api

Does anyone know how to call [snarl](http://www.fullphat.net/index.php) api from java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully called snarl with http://code.google.com/p/jweatherwatch/wiki/SnarlNetworkBridge, indicated in the official https://sites.google.com/site/snarlapp/developers/developer-guide

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Snarl4Java](http://www.dotti.at/projects/Snarl4Java) ? That looks exactly like what you want.